# How do I parse HTML in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, redcloth

I have a string with html tags in it saved.

```
=> "<p>hey man this is crazy g funk</p>\n<p>here i come with another crazy message from..</p>\n<p>dj eassssy d!@#!.</p>"
```

How do you parse this so that it displays the way the HTML tags are implying?

I tried:

```
= Post.text
=h Post.text
= RedCloth.new(Post.text).to_html
= Hpricot(Post.text)
```

Comment: I'd use [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Comment: RegEx? That sounds nuts. Can't Hpricot accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
<%= raw Post.text %>
```

or in haml

```
= raw Post.text
```

The reason is because rails escapes your html and will convert `<p>` into `&lt;p&gt;`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. It was so simple, I had very little idea on how to describe it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generally one parses html with html parsers. What do you mean "so that it displays the way the HTML tags are implying"? Displays on what? Presumably not a web browser..

Comment: Yes so instead of seeing the tags, I see an actually parsed paragraph or h1, or h2 or some specific class i make up in my css.

Comment: You're still not making any sense. "See" it in what? A printed page? A terminal window? A browser window? "actually parsed html" is meaningless, unless you want to "see" a graphical representation of a syntax tree in memory.